# if else statement with multiple conditions

Tags: php, if-statement

What I am attempting to do is set the correct variable before my sql query.  Here is the if statement I have created however I cannot get it to echo out correctly.  Below with the settings provided should echo out fnm however is echoing out nm.  What am I doing incorrectly here to have both variables match in each if statement so I can insert the right data

```
$type = "No Notification";
$remote = "Yes";
if ($type == "No Notification" && $remote == "No"){
$type = "nm";
}
elseif ($type == "Email Notification" && $remote == "No"){
$type = "m";
}
elseif ($type == "No Notifcation" && $remote == "Yes"){
$type = "fnm";
}
elseif ($type == "Email Notification" && $remote == "Yes"){
$type = "fm";
}
else {
$type = "nm";
}

echo $type;
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($type); var_dump($remote);` display? (add the lines at the beginning of your code)

Comment: string(2) "nm" string(3) "Yes"

Comment: Typo: **Notifcation** missing i

Comment: whoops.  missed that, thanks

Comment: @JoopEggen You got me there :)

Comment: Use constants instead of strings like that - you won't have such problems anymore. Even here I would think about using bitmask instead of strings.

Answer (score 2):

Your second elseif has a typo : **Notifcation** should be **Notification**
These things happen :)

Comment: Nice eye. Took me a while to see that.